# Boolean modifier glitch

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I have serious issues with my Boolean modifier. I am using Blender 3.3.1.

I have already tried all the answers in this forum but none of it works. This is not a duplicate...

I thought this is an issue only with one of my projects but I can reproduce it on multiple computers even on startup project:
[image: New project]

I tried reinstalling Blender, Resetting preferences and since I am an IT guy, I even tried turning it off and on again. I also tried recalculating normals, auto smooth and other stuff that I found as an answer here. But none of those helped.

Any ideas?

[image: This is not the same size]

Comment: It's a not a bug but a behavior that occurs when two faces share the exact same place in space. It's called Z-fighting. It looks that your cylinder has the exact same height as your cube. Just size it up on the Z axis

Comment: Hello ! What would you want happen ? You chose intersect mode, and since the cylinder fits entirely inside the cube, the modifier does nothing

Comment: And if you want to do what I suspect - cutting a cylindrical hole into the cube, not only would I scale the cylinder up, but you also have to put the _Boolean_ modifier on the cube, not the cylinder. Nice IT joke, btw (IT guy here, too)

Comment: That's what I am talking about. My cylinderbis twice the size of a cube. When I go into edit mode it is obvious that it ia bigger. It's a simple "make a hole in the cube". Whoever tagged this as a duplicate didn't reead the problem. I have no doubles, this is just cube and a cylinder from the scratch. Also since these are new meshes should be no issues with normals. Can I upload blend file? Maybe driver issues?

Comment: Please see the description I updated

Comment: This is the other way around

https://imgur.com/a/uTN7Fw6